# Chef master role dependency override

Tags: chef-infra, roles, chef-recipe

I have following chef setup:

- master role
- sub-role1/2 contained within previous one

> ```
> {
>   "name": "master-role",
>   "chef_type": "role",
>   "run_list": [
>     "role[sub-role1]",
>     "recipe[sub-role2]"
>   ]
> }
>
> {
>   "name": "sub-role1",
>   "chef_type": "role",
>   "run_list": [
>     "recipe[a_cookbook::recipe1]",
>     "recipe[a_cookbook::recipe2]"
>   ]
> }
>
> {
>   "name": "sub-role2",
>   "chef_type": "role",
>   "run_list": [
>     "recipe[b_cookbook::recipe1]",
>     "recipe[b_cookbook::recipe2]"
>   ]
> }
> ```

Since a version of cookbook is a singleton on a node level it means that if i specify cookbook version in master role, such version is used for all recipes of that cookbook on a node (even for sub-role recipes). This works and is actually the way i need it. 
Unfortunately if i add "recipe[a_cookbook@version]" to master role it automatically calls "default.rb" recipe from that cookbook. **Is there a way to specify cookbook version in role without actually calling the default recipe (or any other recipe)?**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can keep default recipe empty since you don't want to execute it. You can check that some chef cookbooks are missing default recipe: https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/yum-mysql-community